# Probability of a Normally Distributed Random Sample

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

Please help me figure out how to do this problem. I need to be able to do problems like these.

Assuming that customer loyalty has a normal distribution with an average of 75 and a standard deviation of 20 you are to:

A) Calculate the probability that the loyalty of a randomly selected customer is less than 80

B) Calculate the probability that in a random sample of 3 customers all have a loyalty of less than 80.
 Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

Let the loyalty of the customers be $X$.

We have:
$$X \sim N(75,20^2)$$

For part A:
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
P(X<80) &=& P\left(\dfrac{X-75}{20} < 0.25\right) \\
&=& P(Z<0.25) \\
&\approx& 0.5987
\end{array}$$

For part B:

Let $Y$ be the number of customers having a loyalty of less than 80, in a random sample of 3 customers.

We have:
$$Y \sim B(3,0.5987)$$

Then:
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
P(Y=3) &=& \dbinom33 0.5987^3 (1-0.5987)^0 \\
&\approx& 0.2146
\end{array}$$